# use parameter defined mid run at a later stage in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins choice parameter I define mid build(the options come from my git repo so i have to clone it first).

I define the parameter in a script block, since I use a groovy script to filter the options for the choice parameter.
however, I can't seem to use the parameter in other stages of my pipeline.

This is my jenkinsfile:

```
// gets list of currently supported cloud providers from available folders
def findProviders(path){
    def dirs = []
    //get files from root dir, and loop over them to find relevant dirs
    new File(path).listFiles().each { file ->
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            dirs.add(file.getName())
        }
    }
    return dirs
}

pipeline {

    // agents to run on
    agent any

    stages {

        // checkout code from github
        stage('Checkout Code') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master', url: 'https://github.com/castleking1810/infra-configuration.git'
            }
        }

        // find currently supported cloud providers
        stage('Choose provider') {
            steps {
                script {

                    // execute findProviders on build workspace
                    def providers = findProviders(pwd())

                    // prompt user for cloud deployment target, using the providers list generated
                    def provider = input(
                        id: 'provider',
                        message: 'Choose a cloud provider to deploy its managed k8s service:',
                        parameters: [choice(choices: providers, name: 'Provider')]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        stage('plan deplyoment for ${params.provider} managed k8s service') {
            steps {
                dir('${params.provider}') {
                    sh 'terraform init -upgrade'
                    sh 'terraform plan'
                    input id: 'Approve_tf_plan', message: 'do you approve the above plan?', ok: 'approve'
                }       
                
                
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy ${params.provider} managed k8s service'){
            steps{
                dir('${params.provider}'){
                sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('clean workspace'){
            steps{
                cleanWs cleanWhenFailure: false, notFailBuild: true
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

As you can see, I saved the user's choice into a variable called `provider`. I tried using `${param.provider},${provider}` etc. but they don't work...

How can I use my variable in another stage? (Preferably without environment variables/writing to a file and reading it later as these feel like workarounds)

Comment: What you want is not a "parameter" (these are defined in `parameters` block which you don't have, and you can't change them while running), but a _global variable_. For a global variable, just define it outside of the `pipeline` block like this: `provider = null`. You can set it in one stage and use it in another stage.